# What does -fcheck=mem gfortran option check?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, compiler-options

What kind of runtime errors would `-fcheck=mem` option of gfortran catch?

The [manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html) explanation is not clear for me:

> ‘-fcheck=mem’
>
> Enable generation of run-time checks for memory allocation. Note: This option does not affect explicit allocations using the `ALLOCATE`
>   statement, which will be always checked.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely these are allocations that happen on assignment (Fortran 2003 feature) and allocations for heap temporary arguments.

These can fail when there is not enough memory available, for example. I cannot come up with a buggy code that would trigger these checks.